# JDBC and Threading

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a program that needs to query a database in a given interval and with the records it gets call perform some action, then update the table again.

I am using the ExecutorService to run the threads, but am wondering, should each thread get its own connection (because it needs to update database) or can I use the same connection I used to query the initial results?

Can connection pooling work, am on Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 11):

You should always use separate connection for separate threads as the drivers are not thread safe in this manner. A connection pool could help you, as it allows connection reuse in a safe manner.

You could also do a query-dispatch pattern - if I understand your problem correctly -, where one thread is responsible for the querying and starts of N threads which might update the database - all of which have separate connection objects.

You might also consider doing a batch update via the PreparedStatement, so threads don't stumble upon each other in terms of row and table locks, using the following structure:

- 1 query thread
- NCPU processing threads
- 1 batch update thread

Like a mini db fork-join.

**Edit**

Examples on how to do batch update with Pstmt:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE table SET field=? WHERE id=?");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, i * i);
    pstmt.setInt(2, i);
    pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
pstmt.close();
```

Or you could query a Queue in the loop where the update requests arrive from the processing threads:

```
class WhatToUpdate {
    public int id;
    public int value;
}
Queue<WhatToUpdate> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<WhatToUpdate>();

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE table SET field=? WHERE id=?");

int poisons = THE_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSING_THREADS;
while (true) {
    WhatToUpdate record == queue.take();
    if (record == null) { // poison pill
        if (--poisons <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    pstmt.setInt(1, record.value);
    pstmt.setInt(2, record.id);
    pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: Thanks!!!

I have one query thread and N threads for processing. How can i do a batch update using a prepared statement?

Comment: @ kd304: *"You should always use separate connection for separate threads as the drivers are not thread safe in this manner"* Those would be non-compliant drivers, then, wouldn't they? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame9.html

Comment: You can't make the JDBC defiend PreparedStatement API thread safe -- in the sense of multiple threads accessing the same PreparedStatement instance.  If different threads are using different instances, then it is a legitimate driver conformance issue as to whether they are thread safe or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code for the Oracle jdbc [`OracleConnection`](http://www.orindasoft.com/public/Oracle_JDBC_JavaDoc/javadoc815/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) and [`OraclePreparedStatement`](http://www.orindasoft.com/public/Oracle_JDBC_JavaDoc/javadoc815/oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.html#execute()), most of the important methods are synchronized, so they are 'thread-safe.'  Using a single `Connection` across multiple threads will not give you the greatest efficiency, as each thread will need to wait on the operations of the `Connection`and `PreparedStatement`(especially `execute`) to complete before performing their own action.

Comment: @akf: while the question mentions Oracle 9i specifically, it is not a good idea to depend on implementation specific behavior.  Certainly, there's no guarantee that other vendors' JDBC stacks are threadsafe.  AFAIK, it is not required by the JDBC specs.

Comment: You can't make the PreparedStatement API thread safe.  You can't make it thread safe by synchonizing all its methods.  It's a stateful API.  The API would have to be redesigned to make it possible to generally access PreparedStatement instances safely across threads.